# PhoneGap - No splashscreen appearing

Tags: cordova

I'm very new to PhoneGap and installed a sample app like described [here](http://phonegap.com/install/). The app compiles normally and gets installed on my Android device quickly. However, the standard splash screen does not show up. I copied a png image into the platforms/android/res/drawable folder, but have still no success.

The configuration for the splash screen looks like this:

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
```

The images are definitely there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy the splash screen manually into the platforms folder. The file had also to be named "splash.png". Furthermore, I had to add

```
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" /> 
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

into the config.xml file.

Comment: for anyone reading this, the reason the gap:splash tags don't work (and the reason you have to do the manual copying into the platform folders) is because those are for the Phonegap Online Build Service not for when you are using the regular Command Line Tool like @enne87 was.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the plugin via the CLI:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

And then call the show method on the splashscreen object when you project loads:

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

See documentation:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.  Trying to build my rep, please upvote/accept if this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but that wasn't the trick. I had to copy the splash screen manually into the platforms folder. The file had also to be named "splash.png". Furthermore, I had to adapt the config.xml file. I had to add <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" /> and
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" /> respectively. Anyway, thanks for your help!